# Switching between ViewModels in Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am trying to make a WPF application using Caliburn Micro. I have a ShellView with a ContentControl in it on the full page. I am already showing on startup an UserControl in the ShellView s ContentControl(Basically it is a LogIn Page). After login, I want to close the current ViewModel and show another one in the ShellView s ContentControl. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to begin by inheriting your ShellViewModel from Conductor class and other ViewModels (Login and SecondViewModel) from Screen. You can read more on [Screen and Conductors](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/composition). For example,

```
 public class ShellViewModel:Conductor<Screen> 

 public class UserControl1ViewModel: Screen 

 public class UserControl2ViewModel: Screen
```

The ShellViewModel would be conducting between different Screens and has inherited from Caliburn.Micro's Conductor class. When you show a screen, the conductor makes sure it is properly activated. If you are transitioning away from a screen, it makes sure it gets deactivated.

The second change you need to make is in the Context Control in ShellView by binding it to Conductor's Active Item.

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem"/>
```

Finally, you could make use of Conductor's ActivateItem method to switch between screens.

```
 ActivateItem(new UserControl2ViewModel());
```